# count number of rows by differents value - Rstudio - Programming

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to count the number of rows for each differents date I have.

My dataset looks like this (longer with different dates of course - CREATION_DTNR is the date variable):

[image: dataset]

I tried :

```
df <- geocable %>% 
  mutate(count(nrow(geocable))) %>%
  group_by(n_distinct(geocable$CREATION_DTNR))
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: please, post your data sample as text, images aren't helpful since no one will waste their time parsing them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without sample data it's difficult to validate and be sure of the results, but if I have understood correctly your problem and your dataset a possible solution should be

```
library(dplyr)

geocable %>%
  group_by(CREATION_DTNR) %>%
  summarise(n_rows = n())
```